# How to do negative OR on multiple fields in Elastic query

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have an Elastic document of this mapping:

```
{
  "title": "XYZ",
  "description": "ABC",
  "type": "A"
}
```

I want a query that returns all the documents which either have `title` or `description` missing OR both fields are missing. AND type is 'A'

I have tried this but I don't know how can I add the `description` condition.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [{
                     "exists": {
                       "field": "title"
                     }
                   }],
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "type": "A"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "type": "A"
        }
      },
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "title"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "description"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that should work but is there any way to apply the `minimum_should_match` just for the `should` clause? I believe in your query `minimum_should_match` gets applied on `filter` as well.

Comment: minimum_**should**_match only applies to "should" :-) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#bool-min-should-match